# netscape.javascript.JSException: Unexpected error

Tags: javascript, web, jar, applet, netscape

Calling Javascript function from applet giving error

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: Unexpected error: This method should not be used unless loaded from plugin.jar
```

Anyone knows how to correct this error?

Comment: How did you fix this ?